# How to install a new lexer in pygments?

Tags: pygments

I wrote a new lexer for pygments and I try to use it. Thus I look at this page

http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/

where the install procedure is described. They said to do `make mapfiles` but I don't know where.

I look into this two directories where there is the other.py module they talk about.

```
/usr/share/pyshared/pygments/lexers/
```

and

```
/usr/share/pyshared/pygments/lexers/
```

But there is not any makefiles in there. Thus how can I do ?

Answer (score 6):

The blog post [Custom syntax in pygments](http://www.catchmecode.com/2013/03/custom-syntax-in-pygments.html) explains another way to add a custom lexer to pygments:

---

> Pygments enables custom plugins via something called [entrypoints](http://pygments.org/docs/plugins/#entrypoints) in setuptools.

Directory structure:

```
|- FantomLexer
   |- fantomlexer
   |  |- __init__.py
   |  |- lexer.py
   |- setup.py
```

The `__init__.py` file can be empty but it needs to be there so its enough to simply touch it. The `lexer.py` will contain the regex lexer for pygments.

The contents of the `setup.py` goes as following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup (
  name='fantomlexer',
  packages=find_packages(),
  entry_points =
  """
  [pygments.lexers]
  fantomlexer = fantomlexer.lexer:FantomLexer
  """,
)
```

You can then install your lexer via `sudo python setup.py develop`.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution which works. I guess you lexer is in the file `mylex.py`. I did the following under ubuntu 13.10. You need to have root permissions to do that.

1. Copy your new lexer into `/usr/share/pyshared/pygments/lexers/`
2. In the same directory run `python _mapping.py`
3. Do a symbolic link of your lexer into `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygments/lexers/`. For example :

   cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygments/lexers/

   ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/pygments/lexers/algobox.py .

Comment: This worked for me, though I copied the file directly to `dist-packages` instead of `pyshared` (which I can't find).